# Do we need to convert FAQ questions like this to Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, site-definition, community-wiki

Here is a sample question. **[What is Clustered Index?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/866/what-is-clustered-index#question)**
[image]

I think this should be a community wiki question, because PO not pointing any particular issues, just want explanation!

I'm not sure to make it as CW, as its bit old and answered.

Please post your thoughts on this...

Answer (score 5):

Possibly, but be careful -- "what is a clustered index?" might be the wrong sort of question.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/

[image: question decision tree flowchart]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/interesting-question-decision-tree-flowchart.png))</sub>

Comment: "Suggested edits not allowed ... on meta." but I like the ol' flowchart :'( - image migrated to here: https://stackoverflow.blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/interesting-question-decision-tree-flowchart.png

Answer (score 4):

We have provided some additional guidance at the blog:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

TL;DR version

> Most of the time, you should be asking yourself “How can I improve this post so that community wiki isn’t needed?” Community wiki is like a cheese knife: it is a specialized tool to be used sparingly, and only in very specific circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it is a good idea. I was looking for ways to convert nonclustered primary keys into primary keys and thereby I searched all question aboout clusterd indexes and noted that this one was missing the obvious tag and I added it.

Converting it to a CW gives the opportunity to link to further related questions like [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/771/is-there-any-tangible-difference-between-a-unique-clustered-index-and-a-clustered), which shows, that instead of converting the primary key, I can just add a clustered index.

Technically there seem to be the possibility to change a question into a CW or a single answer. In this case it might be the question which to convert into a CW.

Comment: I think the question is because it is already marked as answer, should we feel open to marking it CW for the reasons you list @bernd_k or should we just leave it alone.

Comment: The current question is restricted by to tag to Sql Server. I think a CW about this topic must be platform independent and include Oracle and others and it might be difficult to add this information to the current answers. On the other side the text of the query would be fine for such a CW. I guess we will have similar problems repeatedly. Perhaps we can change the question to include the DBMS from the tag, so that we can use the original question text for a CW.

Comment: @bernd_k yes, I agree with that. How should we phrase this question to make that the emphasis?

Comment: I did some research about Oracle, there seem to be IOT Index Organized Tables which are rather close to SQL Server Clusterd indexes and Oracle uses the term Cluster something completely different. Now I think Oracle is no good example, but I do not know if the other DBMS have something like the SQL Server Clustered Indexes.

Comment: I think it should keep the sql-server tag.  There may be questions that could be made database independent, but not this one.  Even identical terms between different databases can mean the same thing.  Of course this doesn't speak to whether it should be CW or not.

Comment: @bernd_k, @drachenstern - from Jeffs post - yes, its kind a "General Reference" question.

Comment: @Leigh Riffel - maintaining sql-server tag is not a good idea to me, what if there is another question "What is Primary Key?". sql-server tag is acceptable if the question content contains sql server specific scenario or issue faced.

Comment: @Sandy - Then we are in agreement on the concept, but perhaps not this specific case.  "What is a Primary Key?" is applicable to many databases while "What is a clustered Index?" is not.  It is entirely possible that I am not familiar with enough databases and it is applicable to many.  Either way I suppose it wouldn't be too bad having a generic version that simply lists "Not Applicable" for any databases that don't have the feature.